# Buildfire - Load custom plugin on offline mode

Tags: buildfire

Our app is composed of several custom plugins. We would want our app to still work offline so our users will be able to navigate within the app even without internet connection.

The problem is when offline, we cannot switch to another plugin. It doesn't load and only displays the image below.

[image: when offline]

What's the best approach to this?

Comment: Did you contact customer support? Offline mode is a configuration that is only on on certain tiers

Comment: @Daniel_Madain yes, and I was told to post my question here. Your offline mode is in beta and no documentation available. Can we use it on our custom plugins?

Comment: What plugin(s) do you see this for? Are these custom plugins or off the shelf? If they are custom plugins, can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: We see this in every plugin that we have. As stated above, we are using our own **custom plugins**. We use `buildfire.navigation.navigateTo(plugin)` to switch to another plugin.

Comment: @Reactor So just the clarify the specific issue that you're seeing is a result to calls to buildfire.navigation.navigateTo?

Comment: @attila226 Could be. We're trying to load our custom plugins thru that.

Comment: @Reactor My suggestion is to create a bare bones plugin that you're able to reproduce the issue with. This will help isolate the source. Then update your question with the source code used to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your app configuration has offline mode turned on*
The builtin offline support is for the **Datastore** and **ImageLib**.

so if you use datastore to save your content then it should work in offline mode.

As for ImageLib as long as you use `buildfire.imageLib.local` that should support offline mode as well see docs here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-ImageLib

Comment: **The problem is when offline, we cannot switch to another plugin.**
Your suggestion is to make the data available locally. But that's not the issue. It's about loading another plugin when there's no internet connection.
Also for the imageLib.local, your documentation says it's deprecated. Should we be using this? @Daniel_Madain

Comment: Are you sure your app has offline mode turned on? If so, contact your customer service rep and reference this issue so we may take a look at your particular app

Comment: Yes, I turned on Offline Mode and this is still occurring